# Закрывать соединение после полученния данных по socket

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сокет, chat

Предположим, создаётся сеть общения внутри организации. Создаётся поток, который в бесконечном цикле принимает соединения. Как только поступает соединение, создаётся поток для того, чтобы снова в бесконечном цикле пытаться прочесть сообщение от пользователя. Пользователей в данном "чате" может быть достаточно много.

Может быть, при отправке сообщения постоянно создавать новое соединение и сразу же после получения данных его закрывать? Или для каждого соединения в бесконечном цикле пытаться прочесть от него сообщение?

Comment: Постоянно открывать-закрывать соединения туда-сюда намного затратнее, чем работать с одним соединением в цикле

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сокет это файл. Дак вот вопрос, для каждого соединения создается свой файл, или все работает в одном файле для всех соединений и в итоге это не потокобезопасно?

Comment: Во-первых, сокет это не файл, во-вторых, потокобезопасно (пока вы не обращаетесь к одному и тому же сокету из нескольких потоков)

Comment: (Примечание: сокеты и файлы имеют общие интерфейсы для взаимодействия (оба работают через т.н. [«файловые дескрипторы»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)), но сокеты всё равно не являются файлами)

Comment: Много одновременных участников в чате можно поддерживать используя асинхронное IO. Можно вообще в единственном цикле все соединения поддерживать. Пример, [`chat.py`](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/blob/master/examples/chat.py)